# What are the available languages for Google Spell?

Tags: spell-checking

```
https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=???
```

I would like to know what language codes (like "en","de","fr"...) could be substituted for **???**. I am looking for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google](http://support.google.com/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32703), the following are the supported languages:

- Danish
- Dutch
- English
- Finnish
- French
- German
- Italian
- Polish
- Portuguese (BR)
- Russian
- Spanish
- Swedish

I'm sure you can extrapolate the [two letter codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

Don't be surprised if you try other languages and they work as well - it's typical for Google to beta test stuff like this live without letting anyone know.  You could also install the toolbar and see if any other new languages show up.